# Unknown column in 'field list' MySQL Exception

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, ado.net, mysql-connector

how to fix this

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column '@ProductTypeId' in 'field list'
↵   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
↵   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
↵   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
↵   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
↵   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
↵   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
↵   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at EwingsPlatform.Core.Repositories.Implementations.ProductRepository.InsertAsync(Product entity) in D:\01_New Product\New folder\master\EwingsPlatform.Core\Repositories\Implementations\ProductRepository.cs:line 292
↵   at EwingsApp.Controllers.ProductController.PostApplicationProduct(CreateProductViewModel applicationProduct) in D:\01_New Product\New folder\master\EwingsPlatform.AdminWeb\Controllers\ProductController.cs:line 166
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
↵   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
↵   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)"
StatusCode: 500
```

Comment: Include the code that you are executing:\

Comment: Post your code and query. MySQL doesn't use `@` in query parameters so it looks like you tried to use a T-SQL query with MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was in insert SP
`CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`PROCEDURE`product_insert`(
  IN`ProductTypeId`int(11),`

@ is missing `IN`@ProductTypeId`int(11)`

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically saying that something you are trying to use doesn't match up with what the database has.

Please make sure `@ProductTypeId` exists in database.

Comment: Meanwhile check the datatype of that column if exists in database.

Comment: `@ProductTypeID` is a T-SQL parameter name. MySQL doesn't use that syntax

Comment: Thanx i found the problem                                                                           CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `product_insert`(
  IN`ProductTypeId` int(11),   @ is missing here "in`@ProductTypeId` int(11)"

Comment: @Yasiru Why was this accepted? Was the column really named `**@**ProductTypeId` ? You still haven't asked posted *any* code

Comment: As I said: `something you are trying to use doesn't match up with what the database has.`

Answer (score -1):

please Check your table like this id has into table @ProductTypeId

Comment: @Yasiru no there isn't. That's a T-SQL parameter name. MySQL doesn't use that syntax. *Post your code and query*, don't make people guess

Comment: `@` [isn't a valid character](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) in an unquoted MySQL table name. In any case the error complains about a *column*